# Is there a specific sequence to follow when you want to flag+VTC a question?

Tags: discussion, bug, flagging

On October 10, it seemed to me that I was "*first in line*" to VTC a [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/27992).
There was nothing related to IPS, just to promote some standard junk.

After I VTC, and left a comment, I also wanted to flag it so that it disappears from the front page ASAP. My only option was to use "in need of moderator", as no other option was better (ie: no "spam" reason).

I was surprised to see my flag be denied <sup>1</sup>.

Shortly after that, the topic was closed, and with the exact reason I VTC and wanted to flag for.

So, my question is: **what went wrong or what was I supposed to do/modify? My sequence of operation (switched the flag/VTC)? Or isn't it allowed by design? Or just VTC and no flag? Other?**

---

<sup>1. FWIW, I find the (what-I-hope-to-be) canned comment rather patronizing, especially after having raised hundreds+++ of flags on many SE places :)</sup>

[one image, a thousand words...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQa5v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First, such posts should be flagged as Spam or Rude/Abusive as deemed fit. These should not be voted to close.

Now, if you vote to close a question and if it gets closed eventually, you will only see three options in the Flag dialog, Spam, Rude/Abusive, and In Need of Moderator Intervention. It means you can still flag the post as spam or rude/abusive. I am not sure why you saw only the third option. You will see this third option on the posts that are deleted. But looking at the timeline, it doesn't seem the case.

Regarding denial of your flag, there is no need to flag the post for moderator intervention where you can do the same stuff using other types of flags, such as closing the post, notifying that this post is spam or rude/abusive, etc. This option should be used for reasons not available in the flag dialog.

Now, in your case, it seems you didn't have any option other than flagging the post for moderator intervention. So apologies for denying the flag. However, you could have first flagged the post as spam and voted it down, instead of voting it to close. Once a post has a certain score, I guess it is -3, it disappears from the home page.

So, in conclusion, please only flag such posts, not VTC.

Comment: So, bad timeline? Like my actions were "*conflicting*" with some other actions of other users acting at the same time? Because I did DV and VTC. Should have picked a flag 1st? Is that correct?

Comment: I can't say if your actions were conflicting with others. But yeah, pick a flag first for such posts.

Comment: "*You will see this third option on the posts that are deleted*" : sure not the case when I clicked, bg color was not red.